# Subscript and superscript for arbitrary symbols in plain TeX

Tags: superscripts, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

I am trying to obtain a black square with a subscript and a superscript in plain TeX. So far I managed to create `$\buildrel abc \over\square$`.

I could easily use nested `\buildrel`s to achieve the desired result, but then, the font used for superscript is smaller than the one for the subscript, because what TeX sees is a "superscript" above `\square` above "subscript".

How can I solve this? For example, how does TeX implement the `\sum` macro with superscript and subscript that are equally scaled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be declared as a `\mathop`; here is an implementation where the symbol is as high as a summation symbol.

```
% define the extension font also in smaller sizes (not relevant to the problem)
\font\sevenex=cmex7
\font\fiveex=cmex7 scaled 714
\scriptfont3=\sevenex
\scriptscriptfont3=\fiveex

\catcode`@=11

% \squareop is a math operator like \sum
\def\squareop{\mathop{\mathpalette\square@op\relax}\displaylimits}

\def\square@op#1#2{%
  \,\vcenter{
    \kern1pt
    \hrule
    \kern-.4pt
    \hbox to\square@size{#1}{%
      \vrule height \square@size{#1}%
      \hfill
      \vrule
    }
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern-.4pt
    \hrule
    \kern1pt
  }\,%
}

% here we define the size of the square
\def\square@size#1{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 14pt \fi
  \ifx#1\textstyle 10pt \fi
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 7pt \fi
  \ifx#1\scriptscriptstyle 5pt \fi
}
\catcode`@=12

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\squareop_{i=1}^n
\quad\textstyle
\sum\squareop_{i=1}^n
\quad\scriptstyle
\sum\squareop_{i=1}^n
\quad\scriptscriptstyle
\sum\squareop_{i=1}^n
$$

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TeX has the following math "styles":

- `\textstyle`, which is the default style for inline maths (`$...$`);
- `\displaystyle`, which is the default style for display maths (`$$...$$`), which is roughly the same as `\textstyle`, except `\mathop` atoms such as the `\sum` get the `\limits` after them so that the limits are displayed straight above/below the atoms;
- `\scriptstyle` for first level of sub-/superscripts which by default is `cmr7`; and
- `\scriptscriptstyle` for second level of sub-/superscripts which by default is `cmr5`.

It's not clear to me what is your goal here, so maybe you are after `\square` which is a `\mathrel` atom which has limits (so needs to be a `\mathop` atom, too), you could do

```
\def\relsquare#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{\square}\limits^{#1}_{#2}}}
```

and use it with `$A \relsquare xy B`.

You can always change the active style explicitly:

```
\buildrel\displaystyle abc\over{\scriptscriptstyle\square}
```

By the way, `\square` is not defined in plain.

Comment: Thanks for further inside. `\square` is my own macro, maybe I should have stressed it out.